# Accidentally deleted the salesforce authenticator app

Tags: heroku, salesforce

few days ago, I logged in my heroku account and select the MFA with salesforce authenticator app, but accidentally deleted this app and now when I try to log in it says "Use Salesforce Authenticator to approve the request." but in the salesforce auth app I don't have any heroku account linked.

Any suggestions?

I tried deleting cache and cookies in order to get again the main page with the QR code but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this sending an email to support@heroku.com and they solved the problem